# Session in php as cgi script

Tags: php, session, cgi

Is it possible to use sessions in a cgi script written in php?
I have tried but it doesn't work (maybe because session can't create cookies while php executes as script) Is there some alternatives to do something like sessions in cgi?

Comment: what's a "cgi script written in php" in this context"

Comment: Simple, a cgi script written in php (a php program that respects the cgi protocol)

Comment: why is it a cgi script and not a php script?

Comment: Check out [PHP's Session Management Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) and the [SessionHandler class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php). Dissect it a bit, check your headers, it shouldn't be that hard. If you still have issues you can elaborate.